# Finite matrix geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

> If $A_{3 \times 3} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 &1  \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $M = \sum_{i=1}^{20} A^i$ , then sum of all the  elements of $M$ is ..? JEE Mains, July 27 S2 Q.2.

By the standard trick of geometric series, I find:

$$ (A-I) M= A^{20} - A$$

Now I thought of inverting $(A-I)$ but it seems so that the matrix $(A-I)$ is non invertible. Is there any 'patch' to make this approach work?

P.S: I know the way of seeing the pattern when raising powers and adding.

Comment: Do you mean $(A-I)M=A^{21}-A$?

Comment: Indeed @Arthur fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show by induction that$$(\forall i\in\Bbb N):A^i=\begin{bmatrix}1&i&\frac{i(i+1)}2\\0&1&i\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$So,$$M=\begin{bmatrix}20&\sum_{i=1}^{20}i&\frac12\left(\sum_{i=1}^{20}i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{20}i\right)\\0&20&\sum_{i=1}^{20}i\\0&0&20\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}20&210&1\,540\\0&20&210\\0&0&20\end{bmatrix}.$$Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the walks of length at most $20$ in the digraph.

Separate them by the different vertices that appear, since the graph without loops is just a directed path:

If there's only one vertex it's $20$.

If there is exactly two vertices its $\sum_{i=0}^{18}\binom{i+1}{1}$ by stars and bars, which is $\binom{19}{2}$ by hockey stick.

If there is exactly three vertices it's $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{17} \binom{i+2}{2}$ by starts and bars, which is $\binom{18}{3}$ by hockey stick.

it follows the answer is $3\cdot 20 + 3\cdot \binom{19}{2} + \binom{18}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: Notice that the matrix $A$ can be decomposed into the sum of an identity matrix and a nilpotent, that is $A=N+I$, where $N^{\dim V}=N^3=0$.

Therefore we yield $M=\sum_{i=1}^{20}(N+I)^{i}$. Apply binomial theorem to each term and you will derive your desired result.

Besides, $N=A-I$ is not invertible, so please give up the attempt to inverting it.

Comment: Nice trick but how did you compound with the split